# Failed to Load Viewstate in Gridview Editing and Deleting

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, failed-to-load-viewstate

I already searched for possible solutions and I tried the solutions that I searched but none of them really work for me. Everytime I click the link edit button in my gridview to edit certain data I'm having an error message:

> Failed to load viewstate. The control tree into which viewstate is
>   being loaded must match the control tree that was used to save
>   viewstate during the previous request. For example, when adding
>   controls dynamically, the controls added during a post-back must match
>   the type and position of the controls added during the initial
>   request."

I don't remember changing my codes or whatever so I'm really clueless as to what I need to do to be able to fix it. I tried `enableviewstate = "false"` but the gridview disappears everytime I click the link edit button. And also, I click the Edit LinkButton twice. First it just load the same page and when I click again the error will occur saying the Failed to load viewstate. Any suggestions or possible ideas? Thank you very much.

**Edited**

Okay so I viewed my codes and then I saw that in Page_Load I wrote

```
If Not Me.IsPostBack Then
            Me.BindGrid()
        End If
```

but on my Gridview at ASP.Net I didn't wrote `Autpostback = "True"` does it affect this so I'm getting the error? Please help. Thanks

Comment: Are you adding Controls dynamically somewhere on the page?

Comment: Sorry for not being active lately. Yes, I am adding controls dynamically. That's the problem I don't know where is the problem.

Comment: Make sure you (re)create all dynamic controls every time the page is loaded, and that includes a postback.